# How to fetch public file folder from Google Drive Rest Api?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am able to get files from my own drive. But I want to access files/folder which have been made public access by other account users.

Answer (score 1):

The `drive.files.list()` method will find public files. You just need to search for the public parent folder using the `parent` search term.

```
parent in ['0B1dafBJIrDNfdmJUSjBYckZseDg']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `sharedWithMe` search parameter of the `drive.files.list()` method. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters

Comment: file is not shared with me. other user made it public anyone can see it. I only know the folder id. how to fetch files from that folder id. it return me 0 files q =  'folder id' in parents.